# bottom half of product view page is blank

Tags: view

visit this link : http://sitename1/funskool-star-wars-ezra-bridger-mask.html

suddenly bottom half of the page is showing blank. but its was fine as like this :

http://sitename2/funskool-star-wars-ezra-bridger-mask.html

i checked view.phtml file , but its fine.

**system.log**

```
2015-12-31T07:16:39+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: css  in /var/www/html/sitename/app/code/community/Dexxtz/Productzoom/Helper/Data.php on line 281
2015-12-31T07:16:39+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: js  in /var/www/html/sitename/app/code/community/Dexxtz/Productzoom/Helper/Data.php on line 122
2015-12-31T07:16:39+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: price  in /var/www/html/sitename/app/code/local/Webkul/Mpassignproduct/Model/Mpassignproduct.php on line 120
2015-12-31T07:16:39+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: price  in /var/www/html/sitename/app/code/local/Webkul/Mpassignproduct/Model/Mpassignproduct.php on line 123
2015-12-31T07:16:47+00:00 DEBUG (7): Undefined variable: cookieParams/var/www/html/sitename/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php
2015-12-31T07:16:47+00:00 DEBUG (7): Undefined variable: cookieParams/var/www/html/sitename/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php
2015-12-31T07:16:47+00:00 DEBUG (7): Undefined variable: cookieParams/var/www/html/sitename/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php
2015-12-31T07:16:47+00:00 DEBUG (7): Undefined variable: cookieParams/var/www/html/sitename/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php
2015-12-31T07:16:47+00:00 DEBUG (7): Undefined variable: cookieParams/var/www/html/sitename/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php
2015-12-31T07:16:47+00:00 DEBUG (7): Undefined variable: cookieParams/var/www/html/sitename/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php
2015-12-31T07:16:47+00:00 DEBUG (7): Undefined variable: cookieParams/var/www/html/sitename/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php
2015-12-31T07:16:47+00:00 DEBUG (7): call_user_func_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given/var/www/html/sitename/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php
```

**exception.log**

```
#0 /var/www/html/sitename/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
#1 /var/www/html/sitename/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('checkdelivery/c...', Array)
#2 /var/www/html/sitename/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('checkdelivery/c...', 'checkdelivery')
#3 /var/www/html/sitename/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('checkdelivery/c...', 'checkdelivery')
#4 /var/www/html/sitename/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /var/www/html/sitename/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#6 /var/www/html/sitename/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/View.php(73): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#7 /var/www/html/sitename/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/View.php(144): Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_View->initProductLayout(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), Object(Mage_Catalog_ProductController))
#8 /var/www/html/sitename/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/ProductController.php(132): Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_View->prepareAndRender(15245, Object(Mage_Catalog_ProductController), Object(Varien_Object))
#9 /var/www/html/sitename/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Catalog_ProductController->viewAction()
#10 /var/www/html/sitename/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#11 /var/www/html/sitename/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#12 /var/www/html/sitename/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#13 /var/www/html/sitename/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#14 /var/www/html/sitename/index.php(89): Mage::run('', 'store')
#15 {main}
2015-12-31T07:16:38+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: ' in /var/www/html/sitename/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/sitename/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
#1 /var/www/html/sitename/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('', Array)
#2 /var/www/html/sitename/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('', '')
#3 /var/www/html/sitename/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('', '')
#4 /var/www/html/sitename/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /var/www/html/sitename/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 /var/www/html/sitename/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#7 /var/www/html/sitename/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/View.php(73): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#8 /var/www/html/sitename/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/View.php(144): Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_View->initProductLayout(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), Object(Mage_Catalog_ProductController))
#9 /var/www/html/sitename/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/ProductController.php(132): Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_View->prepareAndRender(15245, Object(Mage_Catalog_ProductController), Object(Varien_Object))
#10 /var/www/html/sitename/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Catalog_ProductController->viewAction()
#11 /var/www/html/sitename/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#12 /var/www/html/sitename/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#13 /var/www/html/sitename/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#14 /var/www/html/sitename/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#15 /var/www/html/sitename/index.php(89): Mage::run('', 'store')
#16 {main}
```

Comment: file has php error.. check error in error log..

Comment: i;m checking now.....

Comment: i updated the question

Comment: i replaced the files mentioned in log with correct file, but its not working...

Comment: `exception.log` add this too.

Comment: Please turn on `display_errors` in the `index.php`

Comment: @SanderMangel i enabled display_errors in the index.php

Comment: Does it show an error in the source now?

Comment: @SanderMangel Fatal error: Call to a member function getFrontend() on a non-object in /var/www/html/videomergerapp/app/design/frontend/default/em0113/template/catalog/product/view.phtml on line 235

Comment: @SanderMangel post your comment as answer

Comment: @QaisarSatti Thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: check what's on that line in the indicated file. Magento expects an object but it finds (probably) a null object. It's probably referencing someting like `$this->get[SomethingSomething]->getFrontend()` that fails

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please turn on `display_errors` in the `index.php` to view the error. It will show you the PHP error and the file it's in